# ExtJS and FormPanel: re-load doesn't work (going through the same code)

Tags: extjs, tabpanel

I've got a problem I really can't solve.
Here's my goal: I want to add dynamically Tabs to a `TabPanel`.
I've created my own component called `EmpruntsTabPanel()`
And when I create it I just have to give an array and `EmpruntsTabPanel()` creates count(array)) tabs.
This works perfectly.
So I've done another component, `DossierPanel`.

This one, *once it is loaded*, creates dynamically `EmpruntsTabPanel()`.
This works perfectly.
Errr well. This works perfectly the *first time* it's loaded.
I've made a button to re-load `DossierPanel` (see code below).
I call **exactly** the *same* code (because it's in the same event), and I've checked: it's the same URL, and the result is the same.
So:

1. why does it works the first time, if the `reload` doesn't ?
2. on the opposite, if it works the
   first time, why **not** the second time?

Maybe this has something to do with the code

```
            var res = action.result;
            var tab = Ext.getCmp('tab_emprunts_'+this.id_dossier);
            tab.removeAll(true);
            tab.add( new EmpruntsTabPanel( res.data.emprunts ) );
```

Here's my component (I've removed a lot of `textfield` components for clarity):

```
DossierPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
    closable: true,
    autoScroll:true,

    initComponent : function(){
        var n = this.id_dossier;
        this.title = n;
        this.id = 'id_dossier_'+this.id_dossier;
        this.bodyStyle = 'padding:15px';
        this.labelWidth = 150;
        this.items = [{
            xtype:'tabpanel',
            plain:true,
            activeTab: 0,
            /* (!) Pour qu'un onglet qui n'est pas affiché soit
             * quand même calculé, il faut faire :
             * deferredRender: false
             * C'est très important lorsqu'on fait des fiches
             * avec plusieurs onglets.
             */
            deferredRender: false,
            defaults:{bodyStyle:'padding:10px'},
            items:[{
                title:'Détails personnels',
                layout:'form',
                autoHeight: true,
                defaults: {width: '99%'},
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    xtype:'datefield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Date premier contact&nbsp;',
                    name: 'DATE1ERCONTACTJMA',
                    readOnly: true,
                    format:'d/m/Y'
                }]
            },{
                title:'Adresse',
                layout:'form',
                autoHeight: true,
                defaults: {width: '95%'},
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: [{
                    fieldLabel: 'Adresse 1&nbsp;',
                    name: 'ADRESSE1'
                }]
            },{
                id: 'tab_emprunts_'+this.id_dossier,
                title:'Emprunts',
                layout:'form',
                autoHeight: true,
                defaults: {width: '99%'},
                defaultType: 'textfield',
                items: []
            }]
        }];
        this.buttonAlign = 'left';
        this.buttons = [{
            text: 'Recharger',
            handler: function() {
                this.getForm().load( {
                  url: '/ws/cellulemedicale/jsonEditDossier.php',
                  params: {
                      id_dossier: this.id_dossier
                  },
                  waitTitle: 'Patientez',
                  waitMsg: 'Rafraichissement',
                  failure:function(form, action) {

                  },
                  scope: this
                } );
            },
            scope: this
        }];
        this.on('actioncomplete', function (form,action) {
            if (action.type=='load') {
                if(typeof action.result != 'undefined') {
                    console.log( 'load finished' );
                    console.log( res.data.emprunts );
                    var res = action.result;
                    var tab = Ext.getCmp('tab_emprunts_'+this.id_dossier);
                    tab.removeAll(true);
                    tab.add( new EmpruntsTabPanel( res.data.emprunts ) );
                }
            }
        });

        DossierPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the code that does the initial loading?

`console.log( res.data.emprunts );` is **before** you declare `var res = action.result;` Is this correct? (You may not be seeing the true result in the log)

At a high level, if something is working as expected on load but not after everything has rendered, I would look at if I need to call `form/container .doLayout()` after doing the remove / add magic from the form.

Let me know if this helps.